# develop visual studio add-in with custom intellisense for HTML pages

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, intellisense, add-in

I want to develop a Visual Studio 2010 add-in (or any other solution for that matter) that will support customized intellisense for HTML pages. We use special notation in our HTML pages that is processed on server side. For example:

```
<div id="id1">{foo.bar}</div>
```

I want Visual Studio intellisense to suggest "foo", "bar" etc in the context of {}. I was wondering how hard is it to write such a plugin? Are there any open source ad-ins like that out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you stick with XHTML and can have a custom XML/XSD schema to validate your XHTML. You can do this without using an addin.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/12/07/501466.aspx